# What is the shortest way to write the number $1234567890$?

Tags: notation, puzzle

Here's a challenge : find the shortest way to write the number $1234567890$ .

There is several ways to write the number $1234567890$ :

- $1.23456789 × 10^9$
- $2×3^2×5×3607×3803$
- $617283945×2$

But all these notations are longer. Can you find a shorter notation  than $1234567890$ ?

**EDIT :** For this question, the length of a notation is given by the number of characters used to write the notation on a sheet of paper.

eg : $2×3^2×5×3607×3803$ is 16 chars long.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar forum? Stack Exchange is not a forum.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Why ? Questions, problems, enigmas, aren't they challenges for the math-lover ?

Comment: $x$ in $1234567891$-numeral system where $x$ is used to denote $1234567890$

Comment: In base 1234567890, it is written as 10

Comment: @Kundor Nice try, but that means you'll write it $10_1234567890$ and it's longer.

Comment: @drhab I'm not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: @Pyrofoux: Only if I want to. Do you always put a $_{10}$ suffix when you write in base 10? drhab's answer is the same as mine, but with base one larger, so that 1234567890 is the last "one-digit" number.

Comment: @Kundor I understand, but base $10$ is the common base, if you want to use another base, you must specify it somewhere, and the "information" is longer. However, although that's not the type of answer I'm looking for, this a very clever way to deal with the question.

Comment: You have to define a way to determine the length of a notation. See for example @Alraxite's answer: do you count the width of the graphical representation or the character used to type it in $\LaTeX$ or MathML code, or...? You get the idea.

Comment: One approach is to find some relatively short base, and it shrinks fast, e.g. it is $499602D2_{16}$ (same 10 digits).

Comment: @Pyrofoux Don't take it too seriously. In e.g. the hexadecimal numeral system you have $16$ symbols and $f$ denotes $15$. In the numeral system I mention there are $1234567891$ symbols and $x$ (as I 'decide' here) stands for decimal number $1234567890$. So just one char.

Comment: @rubik Edited. I consider the length of a notation by the number of characters used to write it on a board or on a sheet of paper.

Comment: The tag kolmogorov-complexity is almost good for this post.

Comment: I computationally searched many numbers of the form $\left|\left(e·a^{b^c+d}\pm f·g^h\right)-1234567890\right|$ and haven't found anything particularly close to zero.

Comment: One of possible (far from the best) answers: $$\left\lfloor{\frac{10^{11}}{81}}\right\rfloor-11.$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\quad\quad\quad$$





$$\tiny{1234567890}$$

Comment: The length is measured by the amount of characters to write it on a sheet of paper, so this is no better than the original. I still found it funny, though.

Comment: Excellently funny and clever !

Answer (score 5):

I stated this in a comment, so I might as well put it here. In the commonly accepted base64 notation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), $1234567890 = BJlgLS_{64}$. 8 characters.

Answer (score 3):

It should be
$$
10
$$
in base $1234567890$ of course.

Answer (score 2):

How about: $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{9}i\;10^{10-i}$

---

Alternatively, how about $123\cdots90$? It's only $8$ characters long!

(or the $7$ character $12\cdots90$ if you find the pattern unambiguous enough)

Comment: Interesting answer, but it looks like it takes more space than $1234567890$.

Comment: @Pyrofoux I've added another suggestion. Does that work? :-)

Comment: I love it ! But where is the $0$ ? :p

Comment: @Pyrofoux Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about $KF12OI_{36}$? 
If it were possible you could go up to base $99$, but as far as I know it's defined only for bases up until $36$.

Comment: Base 64 is used very frequently

Comment: @DavisYoshida: I know that for base $36$ alphanumerics characters are used. What do you use for base $64$? Don't you mean the base 64 encoding?

Comment: @DavisYoshida how do you denote $55_{64}$  by one digit -- rubik's notation is only good for base 36 (10 digits + 26 letters)?

Comment: @rubik The standard is A-Z,a-z,0-9,+/

Comment: Here is a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: @DavisYoshida: Also in base 64 it's longer: $MTIzNDU2Nzg5MA==$.

Comment: Note that when I say used very frequently, I am speaking about computer science/web development applications.

Comment: @rubik It is longer if you choose to encode it as an ascii string of 10 characters. That is because each ascii character has 7-8 bits of entropy, whereas a decimal digit has ~3. Also, now that I'm thinking about it the minimal length encoding of 1234567890 is lower bounded by $10\log_2{10}$ bits.

Comment: $1234567890_{10} = BJlgLS_{64}$

Answer (score 1):

In base 32 it is $14PC0MI_{32}$  (9 digits together with the base, 1 shorter than the original)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is acceptable, I've been working on an algorithm to find the numerical equivalence of any sequence given a dictionary.

This is the java code for this: https://github.com/volkovasystems/convert-to-sequence.git

Now by feeding this the following inputs:

1. the sequence index: 1234567890
2. the dictionary: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

You can get the sequence equivalence of 1234567890 from the given dictionary which is:
"**jvqowyc**"

You can even make it shorter or longer depending on the given dictionary.